# python: Building a matrix with weights - using scikit-learn

Tags: python, matrix, pandas, machine-learning, scipy

I have large number of files each file represent an item and file contains labels and their weights reflecting how these labels are relevant to the item.
for example

```
file -> 0001.txt has
skiing-0.789
snow-0.65
winter-0.56

file -> 0002.txt has
drama-0.89
comedy-0.678
action-0.12
```

I want to build a following matrix:

```
     skiing, snow, winter, drama, comedy, action
0001  0.789, 0.65, 0.56, 0, 0, 0
0002  0, 0, 0, 0.89, 0.678, 0.12
```

I went about doing this by reading all the files and generating following dictionary:

```
{0001:[(skiing,0.789),(snow,0.65),(winter,0.56)], 0002:[(drama, 0.89),(comedy, 0.678),(action,0.12)]
```

How can I build matrix from above. I did some research using `TfidfVectorizer()` I can get the counts by passing a list of items to it but I want the matrix with the weights.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for external libraries, such as `scikit-learn`, as Python provides the required functionality easily with dictionary methods. Under the hood, any external library will be following a similar algorithm, described in the next paragraph.

First you'll want to generate a list of all the headers that are distributed over those different files. Then, it would be a cleaner idea to switch the internal structure into a `dict`, such that you can easily retrieve the filling value `0` when the header is not present in a specific file:

```
u = {'0001': [('skiing',0.789),('snow',0.65),('winter',0.56)],
     '0002': [('drama', 0.89),('comedy', 0.678),('action',0.12)]}

headers = []
for key, labelweights in u.items():
    u[key] = dict(labelweights)
    headers.extend(u[key].keys())

print('user, {}'.format(', '.join(headers)))
for k in u:
    print('{}, {}'.format(k, ', '.join(str(u[k].get(header,0)) for header in headers)))
```

You'll want to change the last `print` function into a `matrix.append()` form, if your eventual goal is to present an array of arrays (a 2D matrix) to some other function in `scikit-learn`. I'll leave that fairly easy challenge to you.

Mind you, a very similar functionality, intended for writing to a csv file (or any object which has a `write` method), is provided by Python's [csv DictWriter class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter), which you could use like this:

```
headers = ['user']    
data = []
for key, labelweights in u.items():
    tmp = dict(labelweights)
    headers.extend(tmp.keys())
    tmp['user'] = key    
    data.append(tmp)

with open(outputfile, 'w') as fh:
    dw = csv.DictWriter(fh, headers, restval='0', delimiter=',')
    dw.writeheader()
    dw.writerows(data)
```

If there are duplicate headers in the files, then you'll want to get rid of the duplicates, e.g. by calling `headers = list(set(headers))`, just before the writing/printing code blocks.

Comment: `join(str(u[k].get(header,0))` looks like here is an issue here. It complains saying unhashable type: list

Comment: You seem to be using that small piece of code in a different context, because the code example I gave works. I'd need to see the surrounding context to know more though: which parts of these small code snippets have you changed?

Comment: Also: your edit to my post did not "fix a bug": `some_dict.items()` is not a bug. In Python3.x, `items()` works like `iteritems()` in Python2.x, and `iteritems` should not be used anymore. I prefer the simpler notation `items()`, in both Python2.x and Python3.x. The rest is just preference based. For that reason, I've reverted the post back to the original state.

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis did you already find the root cause for the error "unhashable type: list"? If not, give some context, because the code -as it was posted- works without producing errors.